# QPixmap white display issue

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4

I am trying to show OpenCV images on GraphicsView Widget on Qt with the following python code:

```
frame = self.frames[number]
height, width, channel = frame.shape
bytesPerLine = 3*width
qImg = QtGui.QImage(frame.data, width, height, bytesPerLine, QtGui.QImage.Format_RGB32)
self.scene.addPixmap(QPixmap(qImg))
self.graphicsView.setScene(self.scene)
self.graphicsView.show()
```

The code above shows the image on GraphicsView Widget as totally white, or it doesn't show at all, because GraphicsView Widget background is white.

However, when I change the following code from

```
qImg = QtGui.QImage(frame.data, width, height, bytesPerLine, QtGui.QImage.Format_RGB32)
```

to

```
qImg = QtGui.QImage(frame.data, width, height, bytesPerLine, QtGui.QImage.Format_RGB888),
```

the image is displayed on the widget. However, the image quality is not the one I need.

I have to show my image on RGB quality, without changing any color values on pixels. It is possible by showing my image with RGB32 format. How I can manage that?

Best,

Comment: Are you sure that your image data is in RGB format? Isn't it RGBA?

Comment: Yes I am sure. It has 3 dimensions. It works with format RGB888, but not with RGB32.

Comment: Can you show what you mean with "the image quality is not the one I need"? E.g. what the original image looks like and how it is displayed by your application instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The constructor you are using for `QImage` won't do any conversion.  So the  `format` parameter must match the format of your data.  Your data is in 24 bit format, and so you need to use the `QtGui.QImage.Format_RGB888`.

In any case, the 32 bit format does not differ in quality - it just has an additional `0xff` in front of each 24 bit value.

No other format code is going to work.  If you have a quality problem you might need to look elsewhere.  But you could convert the image to a different format using `convertToFormat`.